# CPU soft cores on FPGA

Tags: cpu, vhdl, verilog, fpga

I need advice here.

One of my mid term hobby projects is to build an instruction set emulator of popular ISAs (e.g. ARM7) on a FPGA device. A lot of people have done this before.

My requirements are specific.  I am looking for a development platform with SoC reference project and onboard peripheral support. Idea is to focus only on the CPU while the rest of the stuff comes from a reference project. It should be possible to compile and download an application in C into onboard volatile memory such as SDRAM have the soft core execute it.

What could be a possible development platform?

Comment: This sound like a question which may do better on [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is a duplicate of the exact same question : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78155/cpu-soft-core-on-fpga

Comment: Take a look at orpsocv2 project - it is easy to take out the or1200 core and replace it with your own wishbone-compatible implementation. It can be configured for a variety of popular dev boards.

Comment: Yes, based on Morgan's recommendation, I posted this query on the electronics stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Altera DE2 boards, make sure they have enough memory for your purposes though.